# JFreeChart - How do I color code multiple rows in a StackedBarRenderer?

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart, graphing

I am working on a program that takes an array of doubles and displays them all in one line on a horizontal bar graph. Right now it works except for the coloring. I have an indeterminate amount of rows so the data is added to the graph like this:

```
public CategoryDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultCategoryDataset bardataset1 = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    for (int i = 0; i < nanoArray.length; i++) {
        bardataset1.addValue(nanoArray[i], "Packet" + i, "Class A");
        bardataset1.addValue(startgap, "Packet Gap" + i, "Class A");
    }
}
```

This stacks the data properly but because there are around 300 different rowKeys it assigns 300 different colors. I attached this picture to show you what it looks like:

http://i.imgur.com/hg33P.png

As you can see this makes the data completely unreadable. What I want is to see bars of alternating colors of red then blue.

Edit: I have found the answer; I used jcern's method. I also wrote a `for` loop that iterates through the length of my double array and assigns a color based on whether it is even or odd.

```
for (int i = 0; i < packetCount; i++) {
        setSeriesToolTipGenerator(i, new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            setSeriesPaint(i, new Color(255, 0, 0));
        } else {
            setSeriesPaint(i, new Color(0, 0, 0));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new renderer and specify that to the plot.

First, you'll create a render that has the two colors you want:

```
CategoryItemRenderer renderer = new StackedBarRenderer {
     private Paint[] colors = new Paint[] {
        new Color(255, 0, 0), 
        new Color(0, 0, 255)
     }

     public Paint getSeriesPaint(int series) {
       return colors[(series % 2)];
     }
};
```

Then, grab the plot and specify which render you want to use:

```
if(chart.getPlot() instanceof CategoryPlot){
  chart.getCategoryPlot().setRenderer(renderer);
}
```

Hopefully, that should get you where you want to be.

Comment: I did try creating a custom renderer where I did exactly what you said. The problem is that since all of my data is in the same column (Class A) it only assigns the first color to all of them. I tried making two columns but then they are seperated (though the colors are different). Is there any way to make them stack with the red on top? I attached the image of what I have now:
[current graph](http://i.imgur.com/sh1P7.png)

Comment: you may want to try setting the series paint on the renderer before you pass it to the plot. You can use something like: renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, new Color(255,0,0)); and renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, new Color(0, 0, 255)); I don't remember whether the series number is 0 or 1 based. I think that is what you are looking for. That will only work for the first two series, but if it does you should be able to override the getSeriesPaint method to return those two colors by testing if(series % 2 == 0) color 1 else color 2

Comment: I have found the answer. I used jcern's method from above. I wrote a for loop that iterates through the length of my double array and assigns a color based on whether it is even or odd.
`for(int i=0;i<packetCount;i++){
   setSeriesToolTipGenerator(i,new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator());
   if(i%2==0){
    setSeriesPaint(i, new Color(255,0,0));
   }
   else setSeriesPaint(i, new Color(0,0,0));
  }`

Comment: +1 for overriding `getSeriesPaint()`. Migrated code in comment to question.